# Error while implementing RadioGroup options selection

Tags: java, android, radio-group

I am getting error in implementing gender selection with `RadioGroup`:

Here is the code:

```
radioSexGroup = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.radiogroup);
register.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int selectedId = radioSexGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
                radioSexButton = (RadioButton)findViewById(selectedId);
                String Gender = radioSexButton.getText().toString();
           }
}
```

And XML for `radiogroup`:

```
    <RadioGroup
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/radiogroup">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                android:text="Male"
                android:id="@+id/male"
                android:checked="true" />

            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:text="Female"
                android:id="@+id/female"
                android:checked="false" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </RadioGroup>
```

This is the Error:

> ERROR java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'java.lang.CharSequence android.widget.RadioButton.getText()' on a
>   null object reference

I know it happens because `getCheckedRadioButtonId()` returns `-1` if no `RadioButton` is selected.

But how can I correct this so that `getCheckedRadioButtonId()` returns the correct Id?

Is their anything that can make the selection mutually exclusive?

How can i unselect a radiobutton after selecting it once, as this is not happening automatically in my case?

Comment: I'm presuming you have set one `RadioButton` checked as default?

Comment: no i haven't done that...how can i do that

Comment: You should at the very least have a single `RadioButton` checked. Since you are using a `RadioButton` it means that it is mandatory to select at least one from the selection (in your use case - it's gender, so it Male/Female). Upon initialization, have either of the two to be checked.

Comment: Can you post your xml where your `RadioGroup` and `RadioButton`s are?

Comment: attached my xml in question

Comment: For your `RadioButton` with `android:id="@+id/male"`, change it's `checked` element to **`android:checked="true"`**. This will require at least for the user to select one Gender.

Comment: There is one more thing...while i'm selecting the radio button it should select only one but in my case both of them are getting selected and unselecting them after that is not possible....once selected it remain that way

Comment: found the solution...never to include linear layout field in the radiogroup